# getting error after processing image. iOS, Swift

Tags: image, image-processing, ocr

I am getting this error when i try to process an image and send to Swift OCR.

> ```
> NSAssert( widthOfImage > 0 && heightOfImage > 0, @"Passed image must not be empty - it should be at least 1px tall and wide");
> ```

if I bypass the handle rectangles function and just call the swift OCR function with the first image taken it works fine, but after putting the image through the function processImage it crashes with the above error.

here is my functions.

```
lazy var rectanglesRequest: VNDetectRectanglesRequest = {
    print("Tony 1 Requested....")
    return VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.handleRectangles)

}()

@objc func processImage() {
    finalImage = nil
    //      finalImage = main.correctedImageView.image

    guard let uiImage = correctedImageView.image
        else { fatalError("no image from image picker") }
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: uiImage)
        else { fatalError("can't create CIImage from UIImage") }
    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(uiImage.imageOrientation)
    inputImage = ciImage.oriented(forExifOrientation: Int32(orientation.rawValue))

    // Show the image in the UI.
    //  imageView.image = uiImage

    // Run the rectangle detector, which upon completion runs the ML classifier.
    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(Int32(orientation.rawValue)))!)
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        do {
            try handler.perform([self.rectanglesRequest])
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}




func handleRectangles(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
    guard let observations = request.results as? [VNRectangleObservation]
        else { fatalError("unexpected result type from VNDetectRectanglesRequest") }
    guard let detectedRectangle = observations.first else {
        //          DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //              self.classificationLabel.text = "No rectangles detected."
        //          }
        return
    }

    let imageSize = inputImage.extent.size

    // Verify detected rectangle is valid.
    let boundingBox = detectedRectangle.boundingBox.scaled(to: imageSize)
    guard inputImage.extent.contains(boundingBox)
        else { print("invalid detected rectangle"); return }

    // Rectify the detected image and reduce it to inverted grayscale for applying model.
    let topLeft = detectedRectangle.topLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let topRight = detectedRectangle.topRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomLeft = detectedRectangle.bottomLeft.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let bottomRight = detectedRectangle.bottomRight.scaled(to: imageSize)
    let correctedImage = inputImage
        .cropped(to: boundingBox)
        .applyingFilter("CIPerspectiveCorrection", parameters: [
            "inputTopLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: topLeft),
            "inputTopRight": CIVector(cgPoint: topRight),
            "inputBottomLeft": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomLeft),
            "inputBottomRight": CIVector(cgPoint: bottomRight)
            ])


    // Show the pre-processed image
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Tony: 1 adding image")
        self.finalImage = UIImage(ciImage: correctedImage)
        self.FinalizedImage.image = self.finalImage

        //          }else {
        //              print("Tony: No corected image......")

        if self.FinalizedImage.image != nil {

        print("Tony: 2 Got here to OCR")
        self.perform(#selector(self.startOCR), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }
}
}
```

with this OCR function

```
@objc func startOCR() {
    print("Tony: OCR called")
            if self.FinalizedImage.image != nil {
        swiftOCRInstance.recognize(FinalizedImage.image!) {recognizedString in
            self.classificationLabel.text = recognizedString
            print("Tony: \(recognizedString)")
            }
        }else {
            print("Tony: No image here")
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you every solve this as i am getting a similar issue?

Comment: Hi DaE, I was able to save it, I forgot to add the answer in. because ciImage is only data the tells the image what filter work it wants on the image it wasn't actually solidified to the image so i had to do that first.  Hopefully the answer i added makes sense...

Comment: as long as you make the ciImage from the filter into a cgImage and then back to uiImage before running the OCR , you should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out. I had to convert the image from ciImage to cgImage and then back to uiImage. as the ciImage is only data of how the filter will effect the image once it is processed so i needed to solidify it first.

a ciImage var inputImage or make input image = another ciImage you are using

```
inputImage = correctedImage

    // Show the pre-processed image
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Tony: 1 adding image")

        let cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(self.inputImage, from: self.inputImage.extent)
        self.finalImageView.image =  UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)


        //Filter Logic
        let currentFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISharpenLuminance")
        currentFilter!.setValue(CIImage(image: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)


        let output = currentFilter!.outputImage
        let cgimg = self.context.createCGImage(output!, from: output!.extent)
        let processedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimg!)
        self.finalImageView.image = processedImage

        // Then start the OCR work using finalImageView.image as the input image of the OCR
```